# Exercício em python

Tags: python

Olá, tenho python como uma das minhas cadeiras deste 2º semestre e preciso de uma pequena ajuda.Tenho um exercício em que não estou a conseguir fazer com que funcione corretamente; aqui está o enunciado:"Escreva um programa que vá lendo do teclado um conjunto de números até que o utilizador insira um número negativo. No ﬁnal deve imprimir o maior desses números."
O código a seguir foi o que fiz mas como disse acima, não funciona corretamente.

```
def read():
  list=[]
  n = int(input("Introduza um nº negativo para terminar:"))
  while True:
    if n > 0:
        n = int(input("Introduza um nº negativo para terminar:"))
        list.append(n)
    else:
        break
  print("O maior nº é:"+max(list))
```

read()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
numbers = []
while True:   
   try:
      n = int(input("Insira um numero negativo para terminar: "))
   except ValueError:
      print("Entrada inválida!")
      continue #continua o loop

   if (n > 0):
      numbers.append(n)
   else:
      if numbers: #verifica se lista está não vazia
         print("O maior numero é: " + str(max(numbers)))
      else:
         print("Não há numero para mostrar!")
      break
```

Há alguns pequenos erros no seu código como: não converter int para string no concatenamento, não tratar excepção e repetir variável "n" sem precisão.
Este último pequeno erro é irrelevante. 
Espero que isto possa ajudar :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Valeu por -1zar

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input('Introduza um número inteiro (negativo para sair): '))
maiorDeTodos = -1

while n > 0:
    if maiorDeTodos < n:
        maiorDeTodos = n
    n = int(input('Introduza um número inteiro (negativo para sair): '))

print('O maior de todos foi {}'.format(maiorDeTodos))
```

Comment: Agradeço-lhe pela sua ajuda.